# __builtin_return_address(0) and ra register have different values

Tags: c, gcc, mips, inline-assembly

I am working with MIPS and GCC compiler.

```
 register unsigned r_a __asm("31");
    __asm("" : "=r" (r_a));
 returnAddress_builtin = (void*)__builtin_return_address(0);
 returnAddress_ra = (void*)r_a;
```

r_a supposed to hold ra register value and  `__builtin_return_address(0)`
yields the return address of the current function.
In my case they are not equal. How is that possible?

Comment: I would compile it to assembly file and look into it.